# What causes a committed update in Hibernate to be NOT visible to other threads?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, quartz

### Problem

There's a Quartz job, let me refer to it as `Job-A`, that runs at a fix interval. On each interval, the job runs in a thread that performs some database updates. However, the next *immediate* run **does not see** the updates made on the prior run. The flow goes like this:

1. `Job-A` runs. Thread: `thread-1`.

   - Pick up entities to process.
   - Commit Connection in the current session to make all changes made since the previous commit/rollback permanent and releases any database locks currently held in it.
   - Mark an entity, herein referred to as `Entity-A`, as `processed`. The goal is to process this entity only **once**.
   - Update and commit the transaction.
   - Refresh the entity so the changes is visible in the succeeding operations.
2. `Job-A` runs again. Thread: `thread-2`.

   - Pick up entities to process.

     - **Expected:** `Thread-2` sees `Entity-A` as `processed` and *skip* it over.
     - **Actual  :** `Thread-2` does **NOT** see the `processed` status of `Entity-A` and *picks it up again*. **Why?**
   - *The rest of the steps are the same.*

### Technology Stack

1. Hibernate 3.6.6

   - session context is `ThreadLocal`
2. MySQL 5.7.3
3. Quartz 2.3.2

   - `Job-A` is annotated with `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`, so multiple instances of Job-A will never run at the same time.
   - `Job-A` runs at a fix interval in seconds.

### Questions

1. I suspect a **race condition** but is race condition a relevant issue in this problem? If so, how do I narrow down the culprit?
2. What are **other possible causes** and how do I track them down?

Comment: How do you get the current session? IIRC, hibernate can reuse the same session from a ThreadLocal store. But if you want to see the new data, you have to start a new session, I thought.

Comment: @GreyFairer, I get the current session via the `SessionFactory`'s `getCurrentSession()` method. Upon getting a new session instance (if not reused) I start a transaction. Yes, Hibernate can reuse the same session from a ThreadLocal because opening and closing a session is expensive.

Comment: Opening/Closing a session is not expensive and should ideally be done for each transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The default isolation level for MySQL is snapshot isolation. It might be that this is the cause. Try setting the isolation to read committed through the JDBC driver configuration.

Comment: The 2 jobs are not running concurrently, so snapshot isolation level should work just fine. But the 2 job have to start a new transaction at the beginning of their execution, which is what seems to go wrong.

Comment: Transactions started are committed at the end of the job.

Comment: Did you try if read committed fixes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` with ThreadLocal SessionContext, you will have multiple sessions, and each session will keep persisted objects in memory.

Quartz uses a thread pool, so it will reuse threads for different jobs. If you have more than 1 thread in the pool, you will have more than one session.

So this can happen:

- Run 1 on thread 1: loads entity A but does not change it
- Run 2 on thread 2: loads entity A and updates it
- Run 3 on thread 1: reuses session from run 1 and reuses unchanged entity A from session memory

Hibernate has this legacy of being able to run without transaction manager, but in cases like this, it leads to unexpected results.

It's better to have each transaction run in a separate session.

```
try(Session session = SessionFactory.openSession()){
  // start transaction
  //...
  // commit transaction
}//auto-closes session
```

If you use a JTA transaction manager, you can also use

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class = jta
```

This way, you can keep using `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`, but it will be opened/closed per transaction, which is the cleanest solution.

Unfortunately, I have no clear example how to configure JTA for your stack.

See also: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-current-session

If you're worried about performance, you'll better configure a second level cache. A second level cache is shared between sessions, and is also transaction aware, so it will contain only the latest committed version of an object.

See also:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-config